# Spring Secutiry logout not destroying JSESSIONID defined in web-fragment

Tags: web, spring-security, fragment

I am using Spring security to secure my rest API. Following are my configurations;

**spring-secutiry.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <!-- Authentication Type and Intercepter Configurations -->
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" />
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />

        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:logout logout-url="/signOff" invalidate-session="true" 
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" 
    class="com.myauthenticator.spring.secutiry.MyAuthenticationProvider" />
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

There is no such implementation for custom logout. I am expecting Spring to intercept call to `/signOff` and destroys token and redirect me to `/` because of the configuration in `logout-success-url` **which should challenge for a BASIC auth once more but its loading my home page.**

It seems like my spring configurations are not correct i.e. not all calls are intercepted by Spring filter. I have following configurations in my web.xml to priorities my web-fragment which contains my Spring Security Filter;

**web.xml**

```
<absolute-ordering> 
    <name>MyAuthenticator</name> 
    <others/> 
</absolute-ordering>
```

Note: My filter and custom authentication are implemented as a web-fragment which looks like as follows;

**web-fragement.xml**

```
    <web-fragment
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        xmlns:webfragment="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd"
        id="T24Authenticator" version="3.0">
    <display-name>T24 Authentication Provider</display-name>
    <name>MyAuthenticator</name>

    <!-- Spring Security --> 
    <filter> 
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>   
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>
.....
```

I think there is something wrong with my configurations! But I can't spot it, can anyone?

Comment: I tried moving my filter to web.xml directly and it still behaves the same...i.e. Spring filter is not intercepting all calls...

Comment: OK...I this is kind of weired but Spring Secutiry Filter does not get invoked if defined inside a web-fragment....:(

Comment: After debugging Spring Secutiry [BasicAuthenticationfilter] class specifically..I found a problem...it has ...  String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

Which means if I access my web application via Browser it will never going to authenticate as I was expecting Spring to challenge user to enter credentials but its just not doing that..